# No sudo after using `visudo -x` option

Tags: debian, sudo

`visudo` warned me about syntax errors so I exited without making changes. I decided to create a new file within `/etc/sudoers.d` instead. Unfortunately, I didn't pay quite enough attention to the manfile synopsis and issued `sudo visudo -x /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter` (the correct argument should have been `-f` not `-x`). This exported my configuration instead of creating a new file and the net result is *no more sudo*.

1. Is this recoverable without rebooting into recovery mode?

   - [This approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196572) did not work for me (using nautilus)
2. Also, is `visudo` supposed to work this way? (not to be snide, but the intended purpose is to protect users, right?) Debian manpage states it at least verifies input and output files are not the same. But apparently it doesn't check that the export destination is appropriate?

*Using Debian 8 (32bit)*

```
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 1 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 1 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 2 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 2 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 3 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 4 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 4 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 4 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 4 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 5 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 6 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 6 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 6 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 6 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 7 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 8 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 8 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 8 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 8 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 9 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 9 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 10 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 11 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 11 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 12 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 13 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 13 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 14 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 14 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 15 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 16 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 16 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 17 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 18 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 18 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 19 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 20 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 20 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 21 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 22 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 22 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 22 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 22 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 22 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 22 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 23 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 24 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 24 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 25 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 26 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 26 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 27 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 27 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 28 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 29 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 29 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 30 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 31 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 31 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 32 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 33 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 33 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 34 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 35 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 35 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 35 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 35 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 35 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter: syntax error near line 35 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Comment: try `pkexec rm /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter` and recreate it again

Answer (score 3):

If you know the root password then you can do

```
$ su root
# rm /etc/sudoers.d/jupyter
```

`visudo` will validate the sudo files *if* in edit mode; you ran it in export mode...